# Use date in mysql database instead ID

Tags: mysql, date, database-performance

How is smart to use date as primary value instead ID?

Where I can get better search mysql database performace:

```
to use timestamp: 1394319600
or to format date and use it as: 09032014
```

09032014 = 1394319600 = 9.Mart 2014

Comment: `PRIMARY` field AFAIK is a unique field, you will have to handle concurrent inserts if it tries to insert the same value.

Comment: I just ask becouse 1394319600 is a large number, how this will afected to search

Comment: The issue is not with search. There is absolutely no measurable difference between querying ids that are small numbers and ids that are large numbers. But what are you going to do when two entries have the same date?

Comment: its not will happend 100%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely should not be using a datetime type of data field as a primary key to begin with.  I would suggest using autoincrementing integer field to guarantee uniqueness.

Now with regards to the datetime/timestamp field itself it is almost always better to use a native datetime or timestamp data type for these columns rather than string representations such a unix timestamps or other formatted date strings.

Why? Because when people put in timestamp data into their database base, they typically get to the point of wanting to run queries against that data.  If you store your data in a non-native datetime format, you will typically need to convert it to such a format before you can use it in typical date/time functions that would be used in this sort of query.  This usually means you lose the ability to leverage any index on the field for the query.

For example, say you wanted to run a query to see all records for the current day.  With unix timestamp field that query may look like:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE FROM_UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp_field)
    BETWEEN CONCAT(CURRENT_DATE(), ' 00:00:00') AND CONCAT(CURRENT_DATE(), ' 23:59:59')
```

whereas with a datetime/timestamp filed it would look like:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE timestamp_field
    BETWEEN CONCAT(CURRENT_DATE(), ' 00:00:00') AND CONCAT(CURRENT_DATE(), ' 23:59:59')
```

Here the simple requirement to use `FROM_UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` on the left hand side of the WHERE condition in the first query prevents use of an index since `FROM_UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp_field)` does not exist in memory like `timestamp_field` would if properly indexed.  This means you now need to do a full table scan to execute that query.  If you have a large table, this could be very problematic.

Comment: I just ask becouse 1394319600 is a large number, how this will afected to search... Probaly the search will be faster if is ID ( 0- 1000 ) instead  1394319600 ... ?

Comment: @JamesD. See my added notes about why you should use native datetime fields.  Really your queries against the field, if done properly in conjunction with a proper index, will typically be much better than when you need to do any sort of data conversion in order to make the query work.

Comment: no no, the date in database will not be in date format, its will be in number format

Comment: @JamesD. That is the main point of my answer.  You should strongly consider using a native datetime or timestamp data type for this data.  It is a much better design in probably 99 out of 100 use cases. IN your question you seem uncertain as to how to store these sorts of values in the database.  I am telling you that any significantly experienced database developer would have you making a datetime/timestamp field in almost every case.

Comment: also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26737360/select-rows-with-same-id-create-json-render-html to know why I asking that ... timestamp date will be just number in database , so my problem will be thats is a big nmber so I worry how that will afect search

Comment: @JamesD. Not sure what the related question has to do with this?  If you are concerned over lookup time between the two format options you mentioned, I would imagine you are splitting hairs assuming there is proper index in either case.  Where you WILL run into problems though is if you have to start doing format conversions in your queries as noted in my answer.  Here you will see orders of magnitude worse performance vs using native datetime/timestamp fields.